# How to retrieve values from an array to get values from other arrays using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a few arrays:

```
cl = ["Chile", "15", "83"];
ar = ["Argentinia", "16.5", "90"];
py = ["Paraguay", "19", "81.5"];

route = ["cl;ar", "ar;py"];
```

Is it possible to loop through one array and get the specific values from the other arrays?
I've tried this which didn't work:

```
$.each(route, function(index,value) {
    place = v.split(';');
    start = place[0];
    end = place[1];

    console.log('from '+start[0]+' to '+end[0]);
});
```

The log should display: `"from Chile to Argentinia", "from Argentinia to Paraguay"`
but it writes just `"from c to a", "from a to p"`.

What did I wrong, how can I read the values from the other arrays?

Comment: Thank you Matt! eval(...) works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially use a hash table:

```
var countries = {
    cl: {name: 'Chile', prop1: 15, prop2: 83},
    ar: {name: 'Argentinia', prop1: 16.5, prop2: 90},
    py: {name: 'Paraguay', prop1: 19, prop2: 81.5}
}
```

Then you can look it up when you need it:

```
$.each(route, function(index,value) {
    place = value.split(';');
    start = place[0];
    end = place[1];

    console.log('from '+ countries[start].name + ' to ' + countries[end].name);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kqcs/2/)

Comment: If possible, I'd move the other values from the arrays in the question to properties of your `countries` object...

Comment: @ShaneBlake Didn't want to make up random key names. Good point though, I've moved them in.

Comment: So often when the solution is elusive, I find my data model was poorly designed...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a hashtable:

```
var hashtable = {};
hashtable['cl'] = ["Chile", "15", "83"];
hashtable['ar'] = ["Argentinia", "16.5", "90"];
hashtable['py'] = ["Paraguay", "19", "81.5"];

route = ["cl;ar", "ar;py"];

$.each(route, function(index,value) {
    var fromTo = value.split(";");
    alert('from '+hashtable[fromTo[0]][0]+' to '+hashtable[fromTo[1]][0]);
});
```